Why do classes with the highest F1 scores not appear during testing phase?
I'm working on a facial emotion recognition problem, trying to classify faces in the following classes: Anger, Disgust, Contempt, Sad, Happy, Neutral, Fear, Surprise, but I have encountered an unexpected issue. After training my model, the evaluation metrics showed the highest F1 scores for classes Happy and Neutral. However, it fails to classify new test images into these two classes correctly.
Here are some specifics:

Dataset: Affectnet, found here. I apply some transformations to the samples:

#for the validation set
transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=1),
            transforms.Resize((48, 48)),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.5], std=[0.5])
        ])
#for the training set
train_transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=1),
            transforms.RandomApply([transforms.ColorJitter(
                brightness=0.5, contrast=0.5, saturation=0)], p=0.5),
            transforms.RandomApply(
                [transforms.RandomAffine(0, translate=(0.2, 0.2))], p=0.5),
            transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
            transforms.RandomApply([transforms.RandomRotation(10)], p=0.5),
            transforms.Resize((48, 48)),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize(mean=(0.5,), std=(0.5,))
        ])


Model: CNN Deep Emotion, implementation taken from here

Data Splitting:
3231 surprise images
1981 disgust images
4035 happy images
2296 contempt images
2574 anger images
2472 sad images
2540 fear images
4100 neutral images

But when creating a dataset instance
class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataset_path, label_mapping, transform=None, balance_dataset=False):
        self.dataset_path = dataset_path
        self.transform = transform
        self.label_mapping = label_mapping
        self.images, self.labels = self.load_images_and_labels()

        if balance_dataset:
            self.images, self.labels = self.balance_dataset()

    def load_images_and_labels(self):
        images, labels = [], []
        for label_name in os.listdir(self.dataset_path):
            class_path = os.path.join(self.dataset_path, label_name)
            if os.path.isdir(class_path):
                for image_name in os.listdir(class_path):
                    if image_name.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.tiff', '.bmp', '.gif')):
                        image_path = os.path.join(class_path, image_name)
                        images.append(image_path)
                        labels.append(self.label_mapping[label_name])
        return images, labels
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.images)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        image_path = self.images[idx]
        label = self.labels[idx]

        image = Image.open(image_path)
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        
        return image, torch.tensor(label, dtype=torch.long)
    
    def get_class_distribution(self):
        """Return a dictionary with counts of each class"""
        return Counter(self.labels)
    
    def balance_dataset(self):
        """Balance the dataset by oversampling the minority classes"""
        paths_np = np.array(self.images).reshape(-1, 1)
        labels_np = np.array(self.labels)

        ros = RandomOverSampler(random_state=42)
        paths_resampled, labels_resampled = ros.fit_resample(paths_np, labels_np)

        return paths_resampled.flatten().tolist(), labels_resampled.tolist()

I balance the samples with the "balance_dataset" function. The final training class distribution is this:
Class distribution: Counter({7: 4100, 2: 4100, 4: 4100, 1: 4100, 0: 4100, 6: 4100, 3: 4100, 5: 4100})

These are the splits in the validation set, that remain unchanged:
808 surprise images
496 disgust images
1009 happy images
575 contempt images
644 anger images
619 sad images
636 fear images
1026 neutral images


Metrics: calculated using the sklearn.metrics.classification_report function.

Here I present my metrics after the training:
Loss and Accuracy for train and validation sets respectively
Epoch 252, Training Loss: 1.1651
Epoch 252, Validation Loss: 1.0238
Epoch 252, Training Accuracy: 0.5565
Epoch 252, Validation Accuracy: 0.6119
Precision: 0.6117
Recall: 0.6119
F1 Score: 0.6098
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

       anger       0.46      0.43      0.44       644
    contempt       0.54      0.66      0.60       575
     disgust       0.41      0.45      0.43       496
        fear       0.45      0.48      0.47       636
       happy       0.87      0.87      0.87      1009
     neutral       0.82      0.85      0.84      1026
         sad       0.45      0.43      0.44       619
    surprise       0.57      0.44      0.50       808

    accuracy                           0.61      5813
   macro avg       0.57      0.58      0.57      5813
weighted avg       0.61      0.61      0.61      5813

Does anyone have any idea on why does the model fail to classify faces to happy and neutral classes? I suspect that the issue might be related to overfitting. Could there be a problem on how the transformations affect training data?
